# SQL Server 2012 Dialog Boxes unreadable on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, ssms-2012

Our development team recently upgraded to Windows 10 and have installed SQL Server 2012 (and have reinstalled with same results), but most of the dialog boxes (backup, restore, etc.) are unreadable due to such a large font size.  We looked and changed every setting that could remotely affect this in Tools/Options but cannot find a fix - does anyone have any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the **text size setting** in the Windows settings?

In your image it doesn't look like the default text size setting.

Go to Settings > System > Display > Change the size of text... check the settings and try changing them, as described here [Windows 10 system font size change](https://superuser.com/a/951206/444112)

Comment: While I can't tell you which setting changed it to make it work, it's now "normal" size where at least I can read it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I have the same problem and I cannot fix it following these steps - do you have any recollection on which settings you changed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...I can't remember which one changed it...we changed a lot.  I will tell you that reinstalling SQL Server did not fix it. It was fixed in the SSMS settings someplace.